# Microsoft Partner Center API non-interactive user based authorization with MFA

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication) shows how to acquire token to be used later in Partner Center API calls. Some methods cannot be called as service principal (e.g. those which are labeled with `"This scenario supports authentication with App+User credentials only."` remark like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-list-of-available-licenses))

but i need to call them in non interactive way. Right now I authenticate with App+User but since February 4 Microsoft requires enabling MFA for user accounts.

With that in mind: how can I modify provided example to make it work with MFA in non-interactive manner?

Answer (score 0):

I seems like it can't be done. This is what I've learned:

> There is no way to automate the consent process used to obtain the
>   refresh token. However, once you have that value it can be used in a
>   headless manner to obtain an access token for the Partner Center
>   API/SDK.

Sample semi automatic solution can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-DotNet-Samples).